# What is "that it needs" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am looking this paper [deep_image_prior](http://sites.skoltech.ru/app/data/uploads/sites/25/2017/11/deep_image_prior.pdf) :

There is a sentence :

> Our approach does not require a model for the image degradation
> process that it needs to revert. This allows it to be applied in a
> “plug-and-play” fashion to image restoration tasks, ...

It is easy to understand without `that it needs` :

> Our approach does not require a model for the image degradation
> process (that it needs) to revert

Easy to understand the main meaning is `does not require a model to revert` .

But by adding `that it needs`, I don't understand what is `it` indicate and what `it` needs. `that it needs to revert` can also be a clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think the meaning is:

> Our approach does not require a model for the image degradation process **that needs to be reverted**.

"There is an image degradation process. The process needs to be reverted. In our approach, we don't need a model for the process."

The only possible noun that *it* can refer to is *approach*. So "the *approach* needs to revert the process". Not the clearest phrasing.